# Get value from html input field

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

How I can get the value of input with `id="new_amount"` and put it properly in Change amount url path. What I am trying right now is obviously not correct:

```
<td>
     <input type="button"
onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update?id=${object.id}&?amount=${document.getElementById("new_amount").value}';" 
value="Change Amount" />
</td>
```

Can someone please help me.

```
<table class=goods>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="object" items="${goods}">
    <tr>
        <td id="name"><c:out value="${object.name}"></c:out></td>
        <td id="amount"><c:out value="${object.amount}"></c:out></td>
        <td id="new_amount"><p>New amount:</p> <input type="number" id="new_amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button"
            onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update?id=${object.id}&?amount=${document.getElementById("new_amount").value}';" value="Change Amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${object.id }';" value="Delete"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr>
    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/addgoods">Add new
        goods</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, It's not correct. Textbox is inside of loop, you cannot use same `id` for all elements.

Comment: You have [illegal HTML](http://validator.w3.org) `<td id="new_amount">` and `<input id="new_amount">`. Which one exactly did you expect `document.getElementById("new_amount")` to return?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some static workaround (for looping) with three rows. It will be helpful to you.

Give id to table, Instead of appending the value directly I am calling function and use hidden value for your `object_id`. Also added class to the element to find that(`ID` is not good idea for repeated elements).

All you need to do is, change static values with your `JSTL` code.

```
<table id="goods">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>New Amount</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="new_amount" class="amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="updateObject(this)" value="Edit" /> / <input type="button" onclick="deleteObject(this)" value="Delete"/></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="goods_id" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="new_amount" class="amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="updateObject(this)" value="Edit" /> / <input type="button" onclick="deleteObject(this)" value="Delete"/></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" class="goods_id" />
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="new_amount" class="amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="updateObject(this)" value="Edit" /> / <input type="button" onclick="deleteObject(this)" value="Delete" /></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" class="goods_id" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Use these functions to get values of clicked row,

```
window.updateObject = function(object){
    // Get nearest text box values based on class.
    var object_id = $(object).closest('tr').find('.goods_id').val();
    var amount = $(object).closest('tr').find('.amount').val();
    alert("ID : "+object_id+" Amount :"+amount);
}

window.deleteObject = function(object){
    var object_id = $(object).closest('tr').find('.goods_id').val();
    alert("ID : "+object_id);
}
```

See the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/26jjuy1z/5/). If you required I can explain more. Hope this helps.

**Update :**

In HTML,
Your actual requirement is looks like below, I have done this using `JSTL`

```
<table id="goods">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>New Amount</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="object" items="${goods}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${object.name}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${object.amount}"></c:out></td>
        <td><p>New amount:</p> <input type="number" id="new_amount" class="amount" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="updateObject(this)" value="Change Amount" /> / 
            <input type="button" onclick="deleteObject(this)" value="Delete"/></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="${object.id}" class="goods_id" />
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr>
    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/addgoods">Add new
        goods</a></td>
</tr>
```

In Script,

```
window.updateObject = function(object){
    // Get nearest text box values based on class.
    var object_id = $(object).closest('tr').find('.goods_id').val();
    var amount = $(object).closest('tr').find('.amount').val();
    //alert("ID : "+object_id+" Amount :"+amount);
    location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update?id=object_id&?amount=amount';
}

window.deleteObject = function(object){
    var object_id = $(object).closest('tr').find('.goods_id').val();
    //alert("ID : "+object_id);
    location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=object_id';
}
```